# Generating signed APK not working: always generates unsigned apk

Tags: react-native, apk, signed

I want to generate a signed APK but I am not able to.

This is what I did:

Generated keystore file with this command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Followed this guide:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content

Generated APK with this command (on windows):

```
gradlew.bat assembleRelease
```

It always generates "app-release-unsigned.apk" file, do not why.

**UPDATED**

Solved, I forgot to add this line to app\build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release // <--- ADD THIS LINE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you add proper code in gradle.properties and build.gradle?

Comment: Yes I did. I added lines as described in the guide.

Answer (score 0):

please mention your

```
build.gradle (App) 

gradle.properties
```

file in question , and files of android/app/

it is possible that you does not have keystore file in  directory android/app/

or have different name other than you mentioned in gradle.properties